# Name of phenomenon of wrong segmentation

Tags: evolution

I think it would be best to illustrate by examples instead of by words:

1. an + other → another → a + nother → a whole nother
2. myn + Edward → my Ned
3. les enfants /le.zɑ̃.fɑ̃/ (French) → les *zenfants → zenfant (Mauritian Creole)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be called ‘[Rebracketing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebracketing)’; the linked page also suggests "juncture loss, junctural metanalysis, false splitting, false separation, faulty separation, misdivision, or refactorization."

Your question is closely related to [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/19019/do-migrating-letters-happen-often-in-languages), in case it’s useful.